# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a log function with sevaral parameters

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, fminsearch

I am trying to find out the parameters for the function below:
$$
\log L(\alpha,\beta,v) = v/\beta(e^{-\beta T} -1) + \alpha/\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}(e^{-\beta(T-t_i)} -1) + \sum_{i=1}^{N}log(v e^{-\beta t_i} + \alpha \sum_{j=1}^{jmax(t_i)} e^{-\beta(t_i - t_j)}).
$$

However, the conventional methods like fmin, fminsearch are not converging properly. Any suggestions on any other methods or open libraries which I can use?

I was trying CVXPY, but they don't support the division by a variable in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be convex (I have not verified this but it could be why CVXPY refused it). We don't have the data so we cannot try things out, but I can give some general advice:

1. Provide exact gradients (and 2nd derivatives if needed) or use a modeling system with automatic differentiation. Especially first derivatives should be preferably quite precise. With finite differences you may lose half the precision.
2. Provide a good starting point. May be using an alternative estimation method.
3. Some solvers can use bounds on the variables to restrict the feasible region where functions will be evaluated. This can be used to restrict the search to interesting areas only and also to protect operations like division and log functions.